# Labeling Excluded Data of Classification in ArcGIS legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, classification

I'm symbolizing a feature class by graduated colors classified with 8 classes, but need to symbolize Excluded Data (Nulls for the classified field). However, the excluded data doesn't label, or at least follow the conventional labels I've set up based on SQL queries for a separate field.

Is there any way to label these excluded features based on a different field (not the null classified field) without having to duplicate the layer?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create label classes by selecting 'Define classes of features and label each class differently' from the Label Method:

[image]

Write a SQL query for each class and you can customize your labels.